# Why User2 unable to see the Knowledge and Article Management Tab?

Tags: profile, permission-sets, user-profile

I have a `Support Representative` Profile and in that Profile I have two users (`User1 and User2`). I have enabled `"Knowledge User"` for both and also given the following permissions to `Support Representative profile`.

```
Manage Knowledge Article Import/Export   
Manage Articles  
Manage Salesforce Knowledge  
Allow View Knowledge     
Knowledge One
```

when I login as `User1`, But can see the `Knowledge tab` and `Article Management` tab. But when I login as `User2`, I don't see the `Knowledge tab` and `Article Management` tab why ??

[image]

Here you go
[image]

Comment: The only possible reason I could think of is the "Knowledge User" checkbox, but you mentioned that it's already checked. I would recommend to verify that again. What is the license type of this profile?

Comment: Please see the updates above. Its really frustrating to see this weird behavior ! Each Setting I have check

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&type=1 -> You pretty much have covered all the permissions required for setting up knowledge article.  Try to setup a new user with the same profile and enable knowledge user, check if he sees the article tab ?

Comment: Hey What if the new user can see the tabs? I wonder then why existing user which is created in that profile cant' see, if one can see that without any issue? Both should faced the problem

Comment: do both the users are using same license? check the user's customize my tabs, clicking on that button. Also try to create a new App like Knowledge Management and expose those tabs. Assign the App in the profile. Secondly, are you using the knowledge in classic or console mode?

Comment: I am using console mode. I have an app already and given the those two tabs (Pls see screen shot above). Both users should have same licenses. How we can check that ? I dont understand "check the user's customize my tabs, clicking on that button" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to the above issue. Each user has to do the `Customize Tab` setting and in that tab setting you need to make the fields visible.